# Why using & to point to Struct s not correct in C++( on Mac)?

Tags: c++, struct

I Use this code to add Node in the linked list's tail.
But it's not correctly running.

```
truct Node {
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node() {
    }

    Node(int i):value(i),next(NULL){
    }
};

void addNode(Node **list, int i) {
    if (!list ||!*list) {
        return;
    }
    Node *n = *list;
    Node *cur = n;
    Node *tailP = NULL;
    
    while(cur) {
        tailP = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    Node iNode = Node(i); // I first create a Node struct.
    Node *node = &iNode;
    tailP->next = node;
}
```

After I changed the function to the following, It's true now.

```
void addNode(Node **list, int i) {
    if (!list ||!*list) {
        return;
    }
    Node *n = *list;
    Node *cur = n;
    Node *tailP = NULL;
    
    while(cur) {
        tailP = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    Node *node = new Node(i); // Now I use new to create a Struct Node.
    tailP->next = node;
}
```

So I'm wondering what's going on? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: `Node *node = &iNode;` is not correct because Node goes out of scope at the next `}` and no longer exists but you keep a pointer for the non-existent node in your list

Answer (score 2):

`Node iNode = Node(i);` is non-static local variable and its lifetime ends when returning from the function `addNode`, so storing its pointer to the list that is used even after returning from the function isn't appropriate.

On the other hand, `Node *node = new Node(i);` is creating an object on heap. Objects on heap survives after returning and is appropriate to use here.

Comment: Can it just means: using：Node iNode = Node(i);  create a stack object? thanks.

Comment: The bug is the `&` part. You can't take the address of a variable that goes out of scope and keep that address and use it after the lifetime of the object no longer exists. Once the `iNode` goes out of scope the pointer you have that points to it is called a dangling pointer. It is undefined behavior to dereference such a pointer.

Comment: So create a Node and then point to it, The pointer may not point the created node. I changed to: "Node *node = &Node(i);", it products an build error:error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Node'      [-Waddress-of-temporary]

Comment: Thankfully this time your compiler correctly complains. It's good that you have it detect this type of undefined behavior.